# Variable declaration without an 'As' clause; Object type assumed

Tags: python, vb.net, syntax

```vb
Dim myArray = New Integer()  {1,2,1,3,3,1,2,1,5,1}
Public Sub Main() 
 Dim mayor As Integer = 0
Dim i As Integer = 0
Do While (i < myArray.Length)
    If ((myArray(i) < 1)  _
                OrElse (myArray(i) > 100)) Then
        Console.WriteLine("enteros fuera del rango de 1 a 100")
        Exit For
    End If
    
    If (i > mayor) Then
        mayor = myArray(i)
    End If
    
    i = (i + 1)
Loop

If (mayor > 0) Then
    Console.WriteLine(mayor)
End If
End Sub
```

I'm trying to run this code but i got this error Variable declaration without an 'As' clause; Object type assumed.

Comment: How do i convert this code to python?

Comment: *"How do i convert this code to python"*. Firstly, that has nothing to do with the question. Secondly, SO is not a code conversion service so simply posting code and asking for a conversion to another language is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

That `myArray` variable is a field, i.e. a member variable. Only local variables can make use of type inference. You must specify the type of a field.

When you declare a local variable inside a method, the compiler must be able to determine the type of that variable. That usually means using a `As` clause to specify it explicitly:

```vb
Dim var As SomeType
```

If you initialise the variable where you declare it:

```vb
Dim var As SomeType = someValue
```

then, assuming that you have `Option Infer On` (which it is by default), you can omit the `As` clause and have the type of the variable inferred from the initialising expression:

```vb
Dim var = someValue
```

In that case, `var` will be the same type as `someValue`. The only reason that you'd need an `As` clause is if you wanted `var` to be a different type, e.g. you wanted a `Control` variable but you initialised it with a `Button` or you wanted an `IEnumerable(Of T)` but you initialised with a `List(Of T)`.

What I have demonstrated here is called "type inference" but it is only valid for local variables, i.e. variables declared inside methods. Fields, i.e. variables declared outside variables, must be explicitly typed with an `As` clause. In your case, use this:

```vb
Private myArray As Integer() = {1,2,1,3,3,1,2,1,5,1}
```

Notice the use of an explicit access modifier (`Private`), the `As` clause and the literal array.

Comment: That was the implication when I said *"More to follow"* but you already have examples in your own code. How can you not know how to specify the type of a variable, especially since the code you posted does it twice? You clearly didn't bother doing any research either, as I just searched the web for your error message and the second match was another question on this very site that provided the example you want. Z for effort.

Comment: The last line of code in the answer will fix your code.

Comment: @Mary, for the record, only the first paragraph was included in the answer when that first comment was posted, along with *"More to follow..."*. I fleshed out the answer just before posting the second comment.